# Get posts that don't have a specific tag in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I know how to get all post with a specific tag. But when I want to do the opposite is does not work.

I am getting all posts that have the tag `Laravel` like this:

```
Post::whereHas('tags', function ($q) {
          return $q->where('name', 'Laravel');
      })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(12)->get();
```

Now I want to get all posts that don't have the tag `Laravel` in them. If I do this

```
Post::whereHas('tags', function ($q) {
          return $q->where('name', '!=','Laravel');
      })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(12)->get();
```

It is returning all posts. It is not working as expected. So, how to get all posts that DOES NOT have the tag `Laravel`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `whereDoesntHave`

```
$posts = Post::whereDoesntHave('tags', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'Laravel');
})->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(12)->get();
```

with this, you'll get only that post which `tags` DoesntHave name as `Laravel`.

Comment: Howllly sh** how did I miss that. Thank you very much! I tried to exclude genres in the function and the solution was to exclude it before that.

Comment: `DoesntHave` is opposite of `has`.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't know it existed. I thought that `whereHas` is used to query all post that actually have tags assigned to them.